# After running the batch file, where is the value of the environment variable set?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I have tried running a batch file(work.bat) with simple content as below:

```
@echo off

rem -------------------------
rem Work
rem -------------------------
set TODAY=FINISHED

rem SETX TODAY FINISHED
```

After finishing the bat file, I checked the Windows environment variables but did not see it(`TODAY`).

> Way 1: From the desktop, right click the Computer icon > Choose
>   Properties > Advanced system > Environment Variables
>
> Or Way 2: From cmd Windows Command-Prompt > enter the command `set`

Where is the value of the environment variable set? Please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the command prompt window close between you running the script and you checking the script? Variables only exist while the environment does.

Comment: After double clicking on the batch file(`work.bat`), I checked the environment variables

Comment: The variables are not persistent after the batch file closes when using the SET command.  If you need persistent variables then use `SETX`

Comment: I understood. Thank Squashman!